# How to improve spark job performance in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, query-optimization, azure-databricks

I am executing the below query on Databricks cluster. And storing the result into DBFS in parquet format.

Here  ***set1_interim*** and ***set2_interim*** are also parquet files having 450 million records each.

```
spark.sql(
          s"""
select *
from set1_interim
union all
select *
from set2_interim
""").write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").option("delimiter","\t").parquet(s"${Interimpath}/unioned_interim")
```

But its taking so much of time to complete the job. If you see below picture out of 230 tasks 229 got completed soon. For last task it takes hours to complete.

[image]

DAG for this job.

[image]

In task page I can see this is running.
[image]

In executors all executors are alive. In running application I don't  know what is Databricks Shell in Name.
[image]

Show Additional Metrics:
[image]

How can in make this job run faster. My cluster configuration are 1TB, 256 core.

Comment: It's typical if 1 task is taking a very long time that means there is data skew.   Have you done any data profiling to see if that could be the case?

Comment: Could you share the metrics of the stage that is taking more time? Your ETL is very simple and the only thing i see is to have 3 workers with 64 cores that can lend to a bottleneck of the garbage collector, something that can be seen in the stage i tell you.

Comment: @Alfilercio :- Added in the Question. Can you pls look at?

Comment: As @MattAndruff said, the metrics say you have a skew data error, one of the tasks takes 10 min compared to the rest only takes seconds. Try solving it by doing a repartition after the union to balance the amount of data between tasks. It doesn't require parameters the method in your case. `spark.sql(...).repartition.write....`